# Игра крестики нолики

Tags: java, android

Когда игрок выбирает 1 игрок и хочет играть ноликом, то первый ход всегда делает крестик.. У меня все работает, при выборе нолика

```
int r = new Random().nextInt(9);

       if(r==0) {
           btn1.setText("X");
           btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==1) {
           btn2.setText("X");
           btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==2) {
           btn3.setText("X");
           btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==3) {
           btn4.setText("X");
           btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==4) {
           btn5.setText("X");
           btn5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==5) {
           btn6.setText("X");
           btn6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==6) {
           btn7.setText("X");
           btn7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==7) {
           btn8.setText("X");
           btn8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
       else if(r==8) {
           btn9.setText("X");
           btn9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
       }
```

Мог использовать вместо этого switch, но не суть важно...

Comment: *arraylist* кнопок создать, не?

Comment: arraylist не использовал

Comment: я не к вопросу, а к тому, что если кнопок не 9, а 90 будет, например? :) Самого вопроса, честно сказать, не понял.

Comment: так а в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Попробую объяснить.. у меня  9 кнопок, ну это простой крестики нолики, тут игрок может выбрать 1 игрок или 2 игрока. потом выбирает крестиком играть или ноликом... так вот, когда игрок выбирает 1 игрок и выбирает крестик, то игрок вставит крестик, а телефон вставит нолик.....  мой  вопрос в том, что когда игрок выбирает 1 игрок и выбирает нолик, то телефон сразу вставит крестик (так как он начинает игру), но я хочу чтоб когда запустился игра, то пусть телефон вставит крестик не сразу, а через маленькое промежуток времени )))

Comment: А этот код какое имеет отношение к задержке перед первым ходом?

Comment: "усыпите" поток , который ставит крестик на 1-2 сек.я бы на вашем месте внимание обратил на постоянно дублирующий код, который вы написали, а не на задержку. вынесите btn.setText("X"); btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow); в отдельный метод, передавая в аргументах btn, а заодно можете и текст , содержаший крестик или нолик. перепишите на свитч, в каждом кейсе которого будет вызываться этот метод. а если еще передавать в этот свитч пемеменную в виде крестика или нолика, то и свитч будет один для всей игры.

Comment: вынесите btn.setText("X"); btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow); в отдельный метод,....  допустим я это добавил в метод btnclick, тут у меня 9 разных кнопок, как вызвать этот метод для btn1 или btn2

Comment: да и еще тут я усыпил, но так сказать тут оно задержит нажатие, когда вот выбираю 2 игрока и потом выбирать нолик, то оно усыпляет вот этот нажатие на эту кнопку выбора нолика... а я хочу усыпить btn.setText("X");

Comment: Как вынести в отдельный метод показываю, код привел ниже. А усыплять надо в месте, где это непосредственно нужно, а не в любом месте кода...

Answer (score 0):

```
    String xo = "X";
    int r = new Random().nextInt(9);

    switch (r) {
        case 0:
            btnclick(btn1, xo);
            break;
        case 1:
            btnclick(btn2, xo);
            break;
        case 2:
            btnclick(btn3, xo);
            break;
        case 3:
            btnclick(btn4, xo);
            break;
        case 4:
            btnclick(btn5, xo);
            break;
        case 5:
            btnclick(btn6, xo);
            break;
        case 6:
            btnclick(btn7, xo);
            break;
        case 7:
            btnclick(btn8, xo);
            break;
        case 8:
            btnclick(btn9, xo);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


private void btnclick(Button btn, String xo){
    btn.setText(xo);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_yellow);
}
```